# If mmap is faster than legacy file accessing, where we see the time saving?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I Understand the usage of the mmap. Considering simple read/write operation on the file, involves, opening the file, and allocating the buffer, read [ which requires context switch, ], and then the data available to the user in the buffer, and changes in the buffer will not reflect into the file unless it is written explictly.

Instead , if we use mmap, writting directly to the buffer is nothing but writting into the file.

The Question:

1) File is in the hard disk, mmaped into the process,  Each time i write into mmaped memory, **is it written directly to the file?**. In this case, **does not it require any context switch**, because, the changes are done directly into the file itself. **If mmap is faster than legacy file accessing, where we see the time saving?**

Kindly explain. correct me if i m wrong also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updates to the file are not immediately visible in the disk, but are visible after an `unmap` or following an `msync` call. Hence, there is no system call during the updates, and the kernel is not involved. However, since the file is lazily read page by page, as needed, OS may need to read-in portions of the file as you cross page boundaries. Most obvious advantage of memory mapping is that it eliminates kernel-space to user-space data copies. There is also no need for system calls to seek to a specific position in a file.

Comment: 1) "it eliminates kernel-space to user-space data copies".  2) Changes visible after an unmap or following an msync call.  Considering point (2), does not it require any system call [ ie: Context switch].

Comment: Yes indeed, but not in every update as opposed to `fread`, `fwrite`.

Comment: so, that means there is a system call invoked, when the file disk needs to be updated. Fine, now when it needs to update the file disk, does not it require to get the updates from the memory [ie: some address mapped to process adddress space], and copy to file?. Why don we consider it as a copy operation from user space to kernel space. Sorry if i am confused?. Kindly explain.

Comment: The kernel then directly accesses the same page as the process without copying

Comment: perreal, I am afraid, i did not understand the your last comment. :(.

Comment: Since kernel knows which memory location corresponds to what part of the file (i.e, mapping) it directly accesses the data without copying it into a kernel buffer.

Comment: Ok, 1) Using fread, fwrite -> File to kernel buffer, kernel buffer to User space. each fread, fwrite opeation invokes system call that to copy from user space to kernel buffer, and then to file in the hard disk. 2) using mmap, write something on the mmaped memory, -> unmap, or msync invokes context switch, and now kernel access the same memory where the process has written, and write to the file. So, here Here though context switch happens, and no extra copy the content from user buffer to kernel buffer, and even no copy from memory to kernel buffer. Is my understanding correct perreal?